# Create Escalation Process

Tags: servicecloud, screen-flow, escalation, teams

I have a little question regarding an escalation process I want to put in place :

Basically, our customer service team is handling contact from all channels on cases. I set up the case record type "Contact Enquiry" for these type of cases.

A lot of time, they need to make an escalation to our logistics team or finance team.

My idea was, create a simple screen flow to create a new "Escalation Enquiry" record type case from the "contact enquiry" case. Put a status on the "contact enquiry" case as "Waiting for Escalation" so agents know the case is waiting for escalation. When logistic or Finance are done with their escalation, they just need to close their "Escalation Enquiry" case with case comments or notes.

I don't want to use the escalation process proposed by SF, because our logistic team should not receive customer reply, and that's become an issue for email to cases where an agent is already speaking with the customer, or even phone/web cases where agents are speaking with the customer by mail.

By using my proposed method, the agent will keep the "contact enquiry" case assigned to him so he can reply to the customer if there is any incoming email, and logistic/Finance will be able to speak with our external partners by mail from their "escalation query" cases.

Do you think this can be a good escalation process, or It will not be really efficient ?

Comment: why not use Case Teams?